# Vector preallocation does not work properly

Tags: c++, vector

i have some trobles with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#incldue <vector>

template <typename ElemType>
class A{
private:

  std::vector<ElemType> data;

public:
  A() {};

  A(int capacity) {
    data.reserve(capacity);
  }

  int GetCapacity() {
    return data.capacity();
  }
};

int main() {
  A<int> a;
  a = A<int>(5);
  std::cout << a.GetCapacity() << std::endl; 
}
```

The output is 0. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The copy-constructor and assignment operator of `std::vector<T>` are not required to copy the capacity of the vector, only the elements.  Because the line `a = A<int>(5)` indirectly invokes the assignment operator (after creating a temporary), the vector in `a` does not have a capacity.

Try changing the first two lines of main to just `A<int> a(5)` and see what the results are.

If you absolutely need the capability to transfer the capacity from one instance to another, you need to define the assignment and copy-constructor of A to both copy the data and assign the capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not implemented the copy-assignment of `A`, preserving the capacity of the vector. The compiler generated copy-assignment of `A`, does ensure the only copying of elements of the vector. The vector's copy-constructor (and copy-assignment) is not required to preserve the capacity of the source vector object. It copies the elements, preserving the `size` of the vector.

That means, if you define the copy-assignment of `A` as:

```
 A& operator = (const A & a) 
 {
    data = a.data;
 }
```

It would still print `0`.

The behaviour you want can be achieved by implementing the copy-assignment as:

```
 A& operator = (const A & a) 
 {
    data.reserve(a.capacity());
    data.insert(data.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
 }
```

Note that `.insert()` only copies the element, because of which `.size()` changes, but `.capacity` remains unchanged. That is why you need to explicitly call `.reserve()`.

Comment: AFAICS, the OP's code only invokes the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Edited. Corrected.

Comment: +1 now.  But for safety, the assignment operator will now need to check for self-assignment.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yup. In fact, there are lots of improvement possible in this code. I wrote a minimal code, otherwise it might confuse the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning to a, the assignment will only copy the values and the capacity.

if you want construct with a set capacity then.

```
A<int> a(5);
```

If you want the capacity to transfer with assignment you will need to write your own assignment operator

```
A& operator=(const A& a)
{
     if(&a!=this)
     {
         data.assign(a.data);
         data.reserve(a.capacity);

     }
     return *this; 
}
```